# Unable to call function with record type input parameter (PLS-00306/00382)

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, custom-type

Type definition (in package):

```
   TYPE t_konfiguracja_raport       IS RECORD(
   nazwa_tabeli varchar2(32),              
   nazwa_kolumny_etykieta varchar2(32),    
   nazwa_kolumny_wartosc varchar2(32),    
   etykieta varchar2(255),                  
   numer_wystapienia integer,               
   odi_sesja_id pg_odi_type.t_sesja,               
   offset integer                          
  );
```

Function declaration - function uses type as input parameter:

```
function pobierz_wartosc(konfiguracja in pg_odi_type.t_konfiguracja_raport) 
  return varchar2;
```

There is also procedure (in the same package as function). I need to use function in procedure, so I'm trying to do it this way:

```
PROCEDURE zasilaj_posg_meldunek_dobowy(
      p_sesja               IN pg_odi_type.t_sesja, 
      o_status              OUT pg_odi_type.t_boolean) as

c_blok              constant    pg_odi_type.t_log_blok := 'pg_odi_raport.zasilaj_posg_meldunek_dobowy';
v_konfiguracja                  PZK_MAIN_V3.PG_ODI_TYPE.T_KONFIGURACJA_RAPORT;  

  begin


    pg_odi_log_err.save_log(c_blok,'BEGIN',pg_odi_const.C_LOG_CODE_DEBUG_01);
    o_status := pg_odi_const.C_BFALSE;

    v_konfiguracja.nazwa_tabeli := 'odi_posg_meldunek_dobowy';
    v_konfiguracja.nazwa_kolumny_etykieta := 'natezenie_ruchu';
    v_konfiguracja.nazwa_kolumny_wartosc :=  'ilosc_w_dniu';
    v_konfiguracja.etykieta := 'Wjechało do RP';
    v_konfiguracja.numer_wystapienia := 1;
    v_konfiguracja.odi_sesja_id := p_sesja;
    v_konfiguracja.offset := 0;

    select pg_odi_raport.pobierz_wartosc(v_konfiguracja) from dual; <--error!


    null;
  end zasilaj_posg_meldunek_dobowy;
```

Unfortunatelly, it doesn't work:

```
Error(90,12): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "PG_ODI_RAPORT"."POBIERZ_WARTOSC": invalid identifier
Error(90,26): PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to "POBIERZ_WARTOSC"
Error(90,42): PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add in declaration:

```
l_function_result varchar2(4000);
```

Change from:

```
pg_odi_raport.pobierz_wartosc(v_konfiguracja) from dual; <--error!
```

to:

```
l_function_result := pg_odi_raport.pobierz_wartosc(v_konfiguracja);
```

... and it should be fine